# Нужна помощь с функцией fscanf на си

Tags: c

не понимаю, чего от меня хочет преподаватель...
у меня в цикле сканируется с помощью фсканф последовательность и тип все ок пока сравнимо с 1, потом выход из цикла. так вот препод просит чтобы я сделала так, чтобы прога выдавала на экран значения, которые возвращает фсканф... я не понимаю как это сделать, не подскажите?

Answer (score 2):

Есть два варианта ответа на вопрос (какой правильный, из вопроса понять сложно):

1) Вывод на печать считанных ф-ей `fscanf` значений:

```
int value, n;
fscanf(file_pointer, "%d", &value);
printf("%d\n", value);
```

2) Вывод количества считанных ф-ей `fscanf` значений (собственно возвращаемого ф-ей значения)

```
int value, n;
n = fscanf(file_pointer, "%d", &value);
printf("%d\n", n);
```

При вышеприведенном использовании `fsanf` (надо помнить, что это функция с переменным числом аргументов) число `n` может принять значения: `1` - все ОК, считано ровно 1 целое число; `0` - целое число считать не удалось; или `EOF` - при чтении достигнут конец файла.

```
int n;
while ((n = fscanf(...)) == 1) {
   printf("%d\n", n);
   ...
}
```

Comment: я сделала как во втором случае) но у меня fscanf стоит внутри цикла while, т.е. считываем, пока не кончится файл. так вот, преподаватель говорит, что надо как то внутри цикла это написать. у меня не выходит. он просит, чтобы обязательно было напечатано значение функции после которого мы выходим из цикла... вот с этим то и встает проблема

Comment: @Арина, ну напишите же в вопросе Ваш цикл. Если он слишком длинный и/или слишком секретный ))  - уберите все строки, кроме тех, в которых используется `fscanf`. У меня есть подозрения, в чем Ваша проблема, но это лишь подозрения...)

Comment: @Арина, цикл выглядит `while(fscanf(...) != EOF) { ... }`?

Comment: почти)) while(fscanf(....) == 1) {....}

Comment: @Арина дополнил ответ. Если бы Вы написали это в вопросе - минусов было бы меньше.

Answer (score 1):

Если не забыл Си, вам я так понимаю ещё типизацию проверять, а вообще если такие вопросы задаёте то может программирование это не ваше

```
    int i;

    int n = fscanf(fp, "%d",&i);
    printf("%d", n);
```

Тут подробнее http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/09/0907.htm

Comment: Во-первых, у вас параметры `fscanf` в неправильном порядке идут, а во-вторых в `fscanf` должен передаваться указатель на переменную `i`, а не ее значение.

Comment: Справедливости ради, надо отметить, что Вы выводите на "экран" не те значения, которые *возвращает* `fscanf`. Вполне возможно, что имеется в виду `int n = fsanf(fp, "%d", &i); printf("%d\n", n);`

Comment: Зато "программирование - это его".

Comment: Дзякуй за правки хоть Си вспомнил